# How to export html into PDF format using code in R

Tags: html, r, pdf

I am trying to make decent quality tables in `R` using `html` code, however I would like to export the final table as a pdf that I can then open up in Illustrator and Photoshop to edit.  I would like to export as a pdf so that I can specify the dimensions of the table.

I have little experience with html but I have got the table to work so far so I will stick with it.  For (now) obvious reasons the only other method I have tried does not work:

`pdf("Table.pdf", width=6, height=4, useDingbats=FALSE, pointsize=12)`
`Table`
`dev.off()`

What I would like to do is export the table below as a pdf with 6" width and 4" height.

```
<html>  
<head>  
</head>  
<table border="2">   
<table width="100%">

<tr>  
  <td><b>Reef</b></td>  
  <td><b>Coordinates</b></td>  
  <td><b>Species Collected</b></td>  
    <style>
  table{
    border-collapse: collapse; //collapse all borders so they don't double up
    border:1px solid #000; //add border around entire table`
  }
tr{
    border-top:2px solid #000; //add single line to top of each row
    border-bottom:1px solid #000; //add single line to bottom of each row
}  
</style>  
 </tr>

<tr>
  <td rowspan="4">Admiral Reef</td>
  <td rowspan="4">25.045 &deg; N, 80.395 &deg;W</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><i>Acropora cervicornis</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><i>Orbicella annularis</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><i>Orbicella faveolata</i></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td rowspan="4">Alligator Reef</td>
  <td rowspan="4">24.842 &deg;N, 80.624 &deg; W</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><i>Orbicella annularis</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><i>Orbicella faveolata</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><i>Orbicella franksi</i></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="4">Jaap Reef</td>
  <td rowspan="4"> 24.585 &deg;N, 81.582 &deg;W </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><i>Acropora cervicornis</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><i>Orbicella annularis</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><i>Orbicella faveolata</i></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td rowspan="5">Little Grecian</td>
  <td rowspan ="5">25.119 &deg;N, 80.302 &deg;W</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><i>Acropora cervicornis</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><i>Acropora palmata</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><i>Orbicella annularis</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><i>Orbicella faveolata</i></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td rowspan="1"></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pdf` function is for *plotting*. R has no direct way of exporting tables as PDF, never mind formatting HTML. But you can easily accomplish this via [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/), which can be called via R.

That said, I would (fairly strongly) suggest not authoring/formatting your tables in HTML. Instead, use something like the [‹pander› package](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/), and maybe take a look at [RMarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) as a general format for you.